# Differentiability of $\mathrm{max}(x, y)$ at $x=y$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

I am trying to figure out differentiability of $\mathrm{max}(x, y)$. Intuitively, it should not be differentiable at $x=y$, since it changes direction "non-smoothly" at those points.

I can not, however, find a way to prove this algebraically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: Write

$$\operatorname{max}(x,y) = \frac{x + y + |x-y|}{2}$$

Answer (score 5):

Take any point $(a,a)$ and prove that the partial derivative does not exist. The partial derivative is $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{f(x,a)-f(a,a)}{x-a}$. The left limit for this is
$$\lim_{x\uparrow a}\frac{\max\{x,a\}-a}{x-a}=\lim_{x\uparrow a}\frac{a-a}{x-a}=0$$
while the right limit is
$$\lim_{x\downarrow a}\frac{\max\{x,a\}-a}{x-a} = \lim_{x\downarrow a}\frac{x-a}{x-a}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x,y)=\max \{x,y\}$. Now look at $f$ on the section $y=-x$:
$$
f(x,-x)=\max \{x,-x\}=|x|.
$$
This function is not differentiable as a function of the variable $x$, so $f$ can't be differentiable.

Answer (score -1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
\partiald{\max\pars{x,y}}{x} = \half\bracks{1 + \sgn\pars{x - y}}
$$

Comment: Formula valid for... $x\ne y$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Yes. I agree. Thanks.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Consider the $\large{\rm sgn}$ function as a distribution and it will make sense.

Comment: Distributions? These seem wildly out of the scope of the question, don't you think?